# Make default printer choice location aware, i.e. based on WiFi network, without Windows 7 Professional

Tags: windows-7, printer, network-printer

I have two printers, one at work and one at home. I'd like Windows to make the appropriate printer the default printer based on what WiFi network I'm connected to or at least in range of (home or office).

I know that this is a feature called "Location Aware Printing" available in Windows 7 Professional, Enterprise, and Ultimate. However, I have Windows 7 Home Premium. Is there any way I can do this?

Thanks!

Comment: If you know scripting, you may be able to hack something together...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I make use of [Mobile Net Switch](http://mobilenetswitch.com/), which takes cares of not just IP addressing and DNS in different networks, but also various other network-specific aspects like default printer, web proxy, folder shares, time zones, configuration scripts, etc. even power scheme and wallpaper.

Personally i feel this SHOULD have been an OS feature all along. Sad.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is only available in Windows 7 Professional, Enterprise, and Ultimate. You can use the included Windows Anytime Upgrade feature to upgrade to one of those versions without needing to reinstall.